# all tests from samba.org troubleshooting pass, but samba not working

Tags: network-shares, samba

I followed closely all tests from the Samba docs troubleshooting chapter:

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch12.html

I am just trying to setup samba shares on RH 7 and see them from Windows.  All tests they recommend there pass, up to and including the last one, Windows `net use` command which works as specified.

I am using their sample `smb.conf` :\

```
[global]
    workgroup = CORP
    security = user
    browsable = yes
    local master = yes
[homes]
    guest ok = no
    browsable = no
[temp]
    path = /tmp
    public = yes
```

I changed workgroup because my Windows workgroup is `corp`.  I did create samba username with the same password as Unix username and that is what I am attempting to connect with, from Windows.  Home directory permissions are 777 just in case it matters.

I can see all the shares from Windows.  I can see the contents of the `temp` share.  I can see the `homes` share as well as my `username` share.  But I cannot see their contents - when I try to double-click on these shares from Windows Explorer, I get "access denied".

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did everything correctly with Samba and Windows.  What I did not know, and Samba documentation does not say, is that by default RH disables samba sharing of home directories.  You have to do first:

> sudo setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on